# Folder ( Report / Dashboard ) permission in managed package

Tags: managed-package, permissions, folder, reports-folder

We have managed package that includes reports and dashboard along with its corresponding folders.

We are able to install package with system admin having following permission => "enable Change Dashboard colors permission" .  System admin user have the access to reports/ dashboard and folders

How do we enabled access of reports and dashboard to other users like standard user ? Is there something that needs to be done during packaging of app ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't generally package folder sharing, since its the installing administrators that will choose the security for the installed items. Instead, the administrators can set the initial settings during installation (e.g. install for all users), and modify them after installation, just as you would for any other folder.

Comment: Could you assist how can I lets say give this access to standard user. When I tried doing share for both Report & Report Folder to standard user. But when standard user tried to access report we get "The report definition is obsolete. Your administrator has disabled all reports for the custom object, or its relationships have changed."    How do I resolve this ?

Comment: @AshishGaonker The user needs access to the underlying objects and fields to avoid this error. You might want to consider building a permission set for your app administrators can assign all the necessary permissions at once.